# How to integrate Google Cloud Messaging 3.0 to a cordova android project?

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

How do I integrate the new Google Cloud Messaging for android in Cordova?

Since cordova project didn't specify project levet build.gradle and modular level build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Cordova PushPlugin: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin. Follow the steps described in the **Automatic Installation** paragraph, and then the **Plugin API** paragraph. You can also have a look at their example at https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/Example/www/index.html

If you're using AngularJS in your Cordova application, you can also use the **ngCordova** wrapper for the PushPlugin. Install ngCordova by following the steps from here: http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/ and then have a look at their examples at http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

You can ignore their note referring to Ionic Push which is another "push notification" service that is currently in an Alpha state. It's an alternative to Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: I'm trying to make a custom plugin using the new approach of GCM.